# wp_schedule_event doesn't work

Tags: wp-cron

I wrote a plugin which now needs a daily scheduled event. For testing purposes I've written an hourly scheduled event.

```php
class MyPlugin {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action('hourly_cron_job', function(){
      error_log('hourly_cron_job action called');
    });

    if ( is_admin() ) {
      register_activation_hook( __FILE__, [ $this, 'scheduleCrons' ] );
      register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, [ $this, 'unscheduleCrons' ]);
    }
  }

  public function scheduleCrons()
  {
    error_log('scheduleCrons called');
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'hourly_cron_job' )) {
         wp_schedule_event(time()+30, 'hourly', 'hourly_cron_job' );
    }
  }

  public function unscheduleCrons()
  {
    error_log('unscheduleCrons called');
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'hourly_cron_job' );
  }
}
```

My error log shows `scheduleCrons called` upon plugin activation. But the action hook never seems to be called. What's going on?

I've tried to `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` but it doesn't make any difference.
Calling `wp_next_scheduled ( 'hourly_cron_job' )` returns the timestamp as expected.
Calling `wp_get_schedule( 'hourly_cron_job' );` returns `hourly` as expected.

**Edit:**

Crontrol displays this error:

```
There was a problem spawning a call to the WP-Cron system on your site.
This means WP-Cron events on your site may not work. The problem was: cURL
error 6: Could not resolve: test.localhost (Domain name not found)
```

Same error is displayed when deployed on a staging server.

Comment: How/when is `MyPlugin` instantiated?

Comment: try the plugin [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) it helps you to see what is set

Comment: @JacobPeattie it is instantiated in the same file, so basically on every pageload when active

Comment: Keep in mind that WordPress 'cron' events don't fire at specific times, they only fire when a user visits your site for the first time after the scheduled time for an event. So if you schedule an event for 10:00, but don't get a visitor until 10:30, the event won't fire until 10:30. So if you're registering this hourly event on a private website, and then leave it alone for hours, the event's not going to fire because no one's visiting it to trigger the event.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes I'm aware, it's not that.

Comment: @Kaperto I installed Crontrol and it shows "Closure" as action. Edit: Did a test, it seems normal as the function had no name. What i didn't notice at first was the crontrol settings page displays an error: "There was a problem spawning a call to the WP-Cron system on your site. This means WP-Cron events on your site may not work. The problem was:
cURL error 6: Could not resolve: test.localhost (Domain name not found)"